# groovy display list<list> with each tag

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Need to display list in table format.

```
var dispList = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]
```

Tried using nested `<g:each>` tag, but no success. Any suggestions ?

format-

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>a</td>
   <td>b</td>
   <td>c</td>
 <tr>
 <tr>
   <td>c</td>
   <td>d</td>
   <td>e</td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `<g:each>` loops do work, but I've generally found I have to use the `var` attribute rather than relying on the default "it" variable name.  If you have an variable called `dispList` in your GSP model then you can do

```
<table>
  <g:each in="${dispList}" var="row">
    <tr>
      <g:each in="${row}" var="val">
        <td>${val}</td>
      </g:each>
    </tr>
  </g:each>
</table>
```